# Renaming pictures to the value in the "Date" field of Windows 10 Explorer

Tags: file-management, windows-10, filenames

I'd like to rename pictures to the value in the "Date" field of Windows 10 Explorer. The pictures I want to rename have no exif, and useless dates on Date Modified, Date Accessed and Date Taken columns. The "Date" column however looks like the accurate date they were taken. The question is: Can you please advise what software I can use to rename the files to their “Date” column, so that the name format equals: 2000-12-28-18h50m40 ? I have tried Advance Renamer, but it seems you can rename to any Date value (Date Taken, Date Modified, etc), except just "Date". [image: This what the names currently look like][image: This is the field I would like to name them by][image: This is what I would like the final outcome to look like]

Comment: Just making sure, have you ever done any computer programming? I could probably create a quick Python program faster than finding a program that does exactly this non-standard date-time format you are asking for (standard: ISO 8601).

Also, a few years ago I've used/liked 'Bulk Rename Utility'. Looks like it can do some stuff with putting dates into the file name: https://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/#features

Comment: Thank you! - I'm going to check that out first thing in the am. Much appreciated. Oh, to answer your Q- I am not, but I agree that it seems right in the middle of those two efforts :-) (just writing it or testing a bunch of sw).